# How can I split a pppoe connection (username and pass) with a switch to two PCs?

Tags: pppoe

I have a pppoe connection with username and pass. One PC with Windows 7, one PC with Windows XP and Qubs 5-Port Ethernet Switch. I plugged in all the cables and my win 7 PC got instant connection. How can I give some of the bandwith to the other PC with Windows XP without the need for another internet connection account ?

Comment: What is your configuration, exactly? "I plugged in all the cables" isn't very clear.

Comment: It's a switch and 2 PCs. There is the main cable from the provider and the two cables from the switch to the PCs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you ll need to get is a Ethernet router so you can plug in all the needed pppoe  information into the router so it acts as a gateway for you. The router will use the dhcp server which will assign the needed ip for the machine.

Comment: I know I can use a router, but I don't have one at the moment. That's why I'm asking if there's any chance I can make this work with only this switch.

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the meaning if PPPoE you see it's Point-to-Point Protocol over Ethernet.  The clue is in the "Point-to-Point" part.  It's a protocol which transmits data from one point to another point.  Only one device can talk down a PPPoE connection at a time.

In order for more than one Point to transfer data to another Point (Point-to-Multipoint) there has to be some device to combine all the points at one end of the link into one (a router).

All a switch does is act like a roundabout in a road system - directing traffic between the different points on a network.

The router takes over the connection of the PPPoE and presents a standard TCP/IP connection to the network using NAT (Network Address Translation) to combine the data from all the computers on your network into one PPPoE stream.

The only way to share a PPPoE connection between multiple computers is to use a router (caveat - if you have multiple network cards in one computer that computer could be used as a router - see Microsoft's Internet Connection Sharing)