# How can I split a pppoe connection (username and pass) with a switch to two PCs?

Tags: pppoe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split a pppoe connection (username and pass) with a switch to two PCs ?](https://superuser.com/questions/179549/how-can-i-split-a-pppoe-connection-username-and-pass-with-a-switch-to-two-pcs)

I have a pppoe connection with username and pass. One PC with Windows 7, one PC with Windows XP and Qubs 5-Port Ethernet Switch. I plugged in all the cables and my win 7 PC got instant connection. How can I give some of the bandwith to the other PC with Windows XP without the need for another internet connection account ?

Comment: Buy a router that supports PPPoE.  Connect the Internet connection to the WAN port of router, configure it, plug your desktops into the LAN ports.

Comment: I don't have a router at the moment. The question was about 2 PCs and a switch.

Comment: Without a router or a second network adapter for one of your computers you are probably SOL.

Comment: @ChristianM, (most) switches are "dumb" devices that are not aware of routing, user sessions, or Internet connections. You need a router that supports PPPoE as Zoredache said.

Comment: Thank you!

PS: Write it as an answer so I can mark it as an answered question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet Connection Sharing will work with some, but not all, of the PPPoE pseudo drivers/adapters. You can try running ICS on the PPPoE network connection by (attempt) enabling "Share Internet Connection" on its network connection.